# Height not 100% on Container Fluid even though html and body are

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less

I have the following layout (I'm using Meteor):

```html
<template name="headerFooter">
    <div class="container-fluid fill-height">
        {{> header}}

        {{> UI.contentBlock}}

        {{> footer}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="home">
    {{#headerFooter}}
        <div class="row body-film">
            <div id="newsfeed" class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-5 block-film">
                {{#each stories}}
                    <div class="story">...</div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/headerFooter}}
</template>
```

and this (relevant) `css` backing it up:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%
} 
.fill-height {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `html` and `body` elements are both behaving as expected. They fill their areas at any zoom level or size.

However, the `container-fluid` with the `fill-height` class added isn't doing the job. It's only wrapping it's content, and not filling to the bottom. This is a problem because it is responsible for adding `body-film` and `block-film` to the page, which are just semi-transparent backgrounds to give the whole thing some color unity.

Here are some screenshots, all with the page zoomed out so the content doesn't fill the height:

[image: My page with nothing selected]

Now here it is with the `body` element selected. As you can see it fills the parent just fine.

[image: My page with body selected]

But the `container-fluid` doesn't.

[image: My page with container selected]

With `fill-height` I've tried both `height` and `min-height`, and they look exactly the same.

Your help is appreciated!

#### Update

I've been trying every possible combination of `min-height` and `height` on these three elements, and nothing works properly.

`height` on all three works when the content is too small for the viewport, but when the content is too large for the viewport, the content block overflows out of the `body` entirely, which means the films are too short for it.

`min-height` on all three seems to me to be the most logical way to go, but it breaks when the content is too small. In this case, the `body` element doesn't stretch to fill its `html` parent.

What's going on!!!!????? Is this a bug in the new [Blaze templating engine Meteor uses](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze)?

#### Update

I've just tried `height: inherit` in my `fill-height`, and it didn't work either. I'm really at the end of my rope. This seems like it should be so simple.

#### Update

Alright, I've got a slight change to happen. With this `less`:

```css
.fill-height {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
}
.body-film {
    .fill-height();
}
.block-film {
    .fill-height();
}
```

The **container-fluid** is now full height, but not the `body-film` and `block-film` which are using the exact same mixin!!

Here is a screenshot, showing the `row.body-film`, which **should** be full height, since the `container-fluid` above it is (take my word for it, the `container-fluid` is now stretched to fill the body).

[image: The row is broken.]

Note, manually adding the `fill-height` to the `html` declaration of the row didn't change anything, it behaves identically as if it were simply receiving that through the `body-film` mixin.

Why is it that some elements don't respond at all to all of these `min-height` demands?

P.S., I'm using Chrome, but it *is* on a ubuntu machine, so I can't be sure if there are any inconsistencies.

### Answer

The following ended up working:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show content that exceeds my height */
}
.body-film {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto; // a value of 'scroll' will force scrollbars, even if they aren't necessary. This is cleaner.
    background-color: fadeout(@studio-bar-color, @studio-body-film-trans-delta);
}
.block-film {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show content that exceeds my height */
    background-color: fadeout(@studio-bar-color, @studio-block-film-trans-delta);   
}
```

The `overflow` attribute was extremely key, and it's something didn't previously know much about. Giving a `scroll` value to the entire body (the thing that needed to be able to move up and down) was the answer, as well as giving the innermost element (`block-film`) the `min-height` to ensure it stretched itself and subsequently all of the parent elements.

Comment: Have I done something wrong with the `html` and `body` heights?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I know you said you've tried every combination, but what about:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.fill-height {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important; /* cross-browser */
    height: 100%; /* cross-browser */
}
```

The problem with setting `min-height: 100%` on the body, is that `height: 100%` on the child div does not actually have a proper parent height to reference, and will not work.

EDIT:

This logic applies to all child divs. So in your case, the body-film div is a child of container-fluid. Because container-fluid now has a `min-height` of 100%, and not a defined `height` (it is set to auto), when you give a height percentage to body-film, it doesn't have a height to reference. It's worth having a read of [MDN - CSS height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [MDN - CSS min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

In other words, if you wish to have a div with a height or min-height of 100%, then all of its parent elements need to have a defined height of 100%, all the way up to the html tag.

What you may need to do is something like this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show content that exceeds my height */
}
.body-film {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This may not be the definitive answer as it depends on what you want exactly, but hopefully this sets you on the right track.

Comment: Neither the first solution nor the `!important` one worked :/ Isn't this strange???

Comment: What actually happens when you try this?

Comment: I'm not sure the header and footer should be in the container. Try taking them out completely and see what happens. It may also be worth posting up the HTML copied from chrome's dev panel

Comment: Both of the solutions were behaved identically to what I posted.

Comment: I'll post the html asap!

Comment: Copying html from the dev panel is always annoying, so I just gave you a screenshot zoomed in far enough to see what I'm seeing. The divs that are refusing to stretch don't have any extraneous parents above them.

Comment: Also, putting the header and footer in their own `container-fluid` outside of the one I'm trying to stretch made no difference.

Comment: I tiny mistake in your HTML can throw everything off, so it's worth removing the header and footer completely until you've got what you want working, then you can add to it. Anyway, I've made an edit which will hopefully help.

Comment: The wrapper bellow the body that envelops the content and stretches html and body to viewport height . Well played this worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly relate to the html sizing problems, I recently discovered a *much* easier way to achieve this sort of "transparent film" thing, using [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

[This article breaks it down pretty well.](http://www.webtalkto.com/three-ways-to-tint-image-with-css3-box-shadow-multiple-backgrounds-and-pseudo-elements/) He also offers other methods, but frankly this seems like the simplest.

```
<div class="example"></div>

.example {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 313px;
    box-shadow: 0px 313px rgba(255, 0, 92, 0.6) inset;
    background: url(/img.png);
}
```