# Height not 100% on Container Fluid in ASP.Net page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Before I write this question I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046801/height-not-100-on-container-fluid-even-though-html-and-body-are) but it doesn't work.

I have this layout in ASP.net page:

```html
   

 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="ToolDesign.Home" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Availability Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <style>
      body {
          position: relative; 
      }
      #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
      #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
      #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
      #section4 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
      #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}


      <!-- make page stretch -->
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show content that exceeds my height */
    }
    .body-film {
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show content that exceeds my height */
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Availability Tool</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section2">Availability Test</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Monitoring</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section4">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>    

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Home section</h1>
      <p>Greeting text</p>

    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Availability section</h1>
      
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
      <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 300%;; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 90px; margin-top: 100px;">Soon..</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Tool version and team name</p>

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

the issue is that height wont fit the full screen as shown in below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of how the above code working with me]

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Always keep hierarchy in mind when dealing with height and percents. If you want a block to stretch 100%, all parents above that element must be 100% height as well. E.g., `html > body > div.div1 > div.div2 { height: 100%; }`. If you want `div.div2 { height: 100%; }`, you need to make sure you set the following accordingly `html, body, .div1 { height: 100%; }`. And in asp.net applications, you will most likely have a form tag just inside your body tag. Take that into account with your hierarchy when adding your CSS.

Comment: Also, make sure to use `* { box-size: border-box; }` when dealing with this particular kind of layout. You can then apply the bottom padding it looks like you need for the sticky footer. Your bottom padding, most likely assigned to the body tag, will be the same value as the height of your sticky footer. You then apply `position: fixed` to the sticky footer to always keep it at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Pegues yes dear thanks, you are right i solved the issue i will update the question

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this problem before - creating a "sticky footer" with Web Forms. The issue was nearly always to do with the form tag which is automatically added in Web Forms project templates. Presuming everything else is correct in your markup and CSS, try this:

```
html, body, form
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Armed with this knowledge of the "form" tag problem with Web Forms (the real problem being that we forget to add 'form' to our CSS selector), here is the basic theory of for creating sticky footers:

https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Haven't had time to try out your code, but I notice inline CSS, which you need to move to a style sheet, etc. Best suggestion is to create a simple form and master page for testing a solution - keep content short in your test page, then verify that it works.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have tried to add `form` tag as you mentioned but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

## The Answer

The issue was with the `css` style.
**First of all** taking the `section` style:

```
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section4 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

noticing that `height:500px` must be `100%` since we need each section to fill in the screan.

**Second** we need to add the `form` tag in `body` style to be like as well moving all CSS which belong to body into this block:

```
html, body, form {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Finaly we remove the unnecessary CSS and the final CSS code will be:

```
     html, body, form {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        } 
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section4 {padding-top:50px;height:100%;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
```